# How to send a form without refreshing the page?

Tags: php, html, html-email

I don't know PHP.

I don't want the user to go to `http://www.example.com/feedback-thanks.html` after sending the form. What I want is text below the sent button or anything **without refreshing the page**.

I removed `header( "Location: http://www.example.com/feedback-thanks.html" );` but i don't receive the e-mail and the user is redirected to feedback.php... :(

**html**

```
<form method="post" action="feedback.php">
<input name="email" type="email"/>
<textarea name="message" id="feedback-textarea" autofocus="autofocus" required="required" ></textarea>
<button type="submit" id="feedback-button-send">send</button>
</form>
```

**feedback.php**

```
<?php
  $email = $_REQUEST['email'] ;
  $message = $_REQUEST['message'] ;

  mail( "abcde@gmail.com", "Subject Here",
    $message, "From: $email" );
  header( "Location: http://www.example.com/feedback-thanks.html" );
?>
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You will have to use `$.ajax()` for that

- http://net.tutsplus.com/tutorials/javascript-ajax/5-ways-to-make-ajax-calls-with-jquery/
- http://www.sitepoint.com/ajax-jquery/

this is what I use in one of my apps

```
$('#submitSearch').click(function() {

        var formData = {
            searchData: $('#searchData').val(),
        };

        $.ajax({
            url: siteUrl + 'fetch/search',
            type: "POST",
            data: formData,
            cache: true,            
            beforeSend:function(){
                jQuery('#main').html('<div class="loading"><img src="' + siteUrl + 'resources/imgs/ajax-loader.gif" alt="Loading..." /></div>');
            },
            success: function(data) {
                jQuery('#main').empty();
                jQuery('#main').append(data);
            },
            error:function(x,e){
                if(x.status==0){
                    alert('You are offline!!\n Please Check Your Network.');
                }else if(x.status==404){
                    alert('Requested URL not found.');
                }else if(x.status==500){
                    alert('Internel Server Error.');
                }else if(e=='parsererror'){
                    alert('Error.\nParsing JSON Request failed.');
                }else if(e=='timeout'){
                    alert('Request Time out.');
                }else {
                    alert('Unknow Error.\n'+x.responseText);
                }
            }
        });
        return false;
    });
```

Comment: Thanks a lot! that helped me and now I'm learning a little bit more about AJAX.

Answer (score 0):

I'd suggest using a Javascript framework like jQuery and use it's AJAX function. Lots of tutorials to find on the internet if you Google for it.

Start at [jquery.com](http://jquery.com)

Answer (score 0):

1. posibility - Use ajax in any form - jQuery, plain, etc ... see Google
2. posibility - Create hidden iframe with name="sender" and use form target attribute ( I'm not sure if it is valid, but it works without javascript )

Answer (score 0):

If you want what i want just look at this tutorial (with demo)

http://net.tutsplus.com/tutorials/javascript-ajax/submit-a-form-without-page-refresh-using-jquery/