# Pass javascript variables into Database with MySQL and PHP

Tags: php, javascript, mysql

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How to pass a variable / data from javascript to php and vice versa?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/406316/how-to-pass-a-variable-data-from-javascript-to-php-and-vice-versa)

I have 3 javascript variables which gives me an id, a name and a surname as such:

```
    if (!response.error) {

    document.getElementById("meName").innerHTML = response.id 
                                                 + " " + response.name
                                                 + " " + response.surname ;
                        }
```

Now I want to pass those variables (`response.id`, `response.name` and `response.surname`) into my database.

Something like this:

```
<?php

    $query = mysql_query("INSERT INTO users (id, name, surname) VALUES 
 ('response.id', 'response.name', 'response.surname')") or die(mysql_error());

$result = mysql_fetch_array($query);
return $result;

?>
```

**How can I do this?**

Comment: First of all you have to understand the difference between client and server.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is what you need:

```
        if (!response.error) {
                    var uid = response.id;
                var firstname = response.name;  
                    var surname = response.surname  

                    if (window.XMLHttpRequest) {
                        xmlhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
                    }

                    xmlhttp.open("GET", "ajax.php?uid=" + uid + "&firstname=" + firstname + "&surname=" +  surname , true);
                    xmlhttp.send();

                    return false;

        }
```

and in your ajax file:

```
<?php include("YOUR_CONNECTION_FILE.php");


$uid = mysql_real_escape_string($_GET['uid']);
$firstname = mysql_real_escape_string($_GET['firstname']);
$username = mysql_real_escape_string($_GET['surname']);


$query = mysql_query(" YOUR MYSQL QUERY ") or die(mysql_error());  
?>
```

Answer (score 1):

Well, ajax would be the best choice in your case.

Check my answer here [How to send a form without refreshing the page?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8819049/how-to-sent-a-form-without-refreshing-the-page/8819077#8819077)

Check out some documentation also:

### jQuery Documentation

- [jQuery.ajax() - jQuery API](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/)
- [Ajax - jQuery API](http://api.jquery.com/category/ajax/)

### Tutorials

- [Net Tuts+ - 5 Ways to Make Ajax Calls with jQuery](http://net.tutsplus.com/tutorials/javascript-ajax/5-ways-to-make-ajax-calls-with-jquery/)
- [Beginners Guide to Using AJAX with jQuery](http://www.devirtuoso.com/2009/07/beginners-guide-to-using-ajax-with-jquery/)

Answer (score 1):

I'm guessing you're trying to pass the javascript variables to php.

In order to do this you need to use a POST or GET method.

[This question's answer will help.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1917576/how-to-pass-javascript-variables-to-php)

Answer (score 0):

You'd need to make an AJAX call to a separate PHP script which stores the variables.

Javascript runs browser-side, whereas PHP runs on the server - by the time the browser is running the Javascript code in the page, it has already finished running on the server and thus all of the PHP code has already executed.

Comment: That is why I came here and asked this question otherwise I would just go do it, dont you think? You are answering my question.

Answer (score -1):

I believe that response is your return via ajax, if so, you should check two things

First, set the ajax dataType to 'json'.

Second, replace

```
return $result
```

to

```
return json_encode($result);
```

By.